# datatable disable initial sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am using datatables for user input in which i am inserting new rows.

Following is my code :

```
$('#invoice-content-table').dataTable({
            "bPaginate": false,
            "sScrollY": "150px",
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bSort": false,
            "bInfo": false,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "aaSorting": [],
            "bDestroy":true,
            "aoColumns": [
                           { "sWidth": "170px", "bSortable": false,"asSorting":[] },
                           { "sWidth": "30px", "bSortable": false, "asSorting": [] },
                           { "sWidth": "30px", "bSortable": false, "asSorting": [] },
                           { "sWidth": "40px", "bSortable": false, "asSorting": [] },
                           { "sWidth": "25px", "bSortable": false, "asSorting": [] },
                           { "sWidth": "25px", "bSortable": false, "asSorting": [] },
                           { "sWidth": "25px", "bSortable": false, "asSorting": [] },
                           { "sWidth": "25px", "bSortable": false, "asSorting": [] },
                           { "sWidth": "25px", "bSortable": false, "asSorting": [] },
                           { "sWidth": "30px", "bSortable": false, "asSorting": [] },
                           { "sWidth": "50px", "bSortable": false, "asSorting": [] }

                         ]
        });
```

The issue is whenever is insert new row, it gets sorted by default. I have tried setting 
aaSorting : [] array to null, but still no luck. How to disable it ?

Comment: do u reload the entire page after inserting new row or just refresh the part containing datatable ?

Comment: i refresh the part ..